# Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0.0 - Browser Link refresh feature causes an error in the web browser dubug console

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Getting acustomed with the latest Visual Studio.

In my NET Core 5 web app, each time I press the save button in VS, the browser automatically refreshes with the updated code (i.e. after making some modifications to javscript)

I get the error below in the debug console and see that VS has added some unexpected script to my page:

[image]

```
<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost:44399/46dcd6a7a1bc4303ab72eae2b0033153/browserLink" 
async="async" id="__browserLink_initializationData" data-requestId="c33a3fe85ae64c3391c704f430971956" 
data-requestMappingFromServer="False"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

<script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script></body>
```

I kinda like the new feature but I really dont want console errors when trying to test my app and code for stability. Is there a way to sort this error? expect its eomthig to do with the fact that I have cross-site scripting protection baked into the NET Core environment.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, we are seeing the same thing?

Comment: Nope I didn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This went away for us when we switched off "Projects and Solutions > ASP.NET Core > CSS Hot Reload". But this may be unacceptable if you need hot reloading of CSS.